# Morphology of 'order' and 'supervisor'

Tags: morphology

I wonder how many morphemes are at work in words '**order**' and '**supervisor**', used in the structure 'the unbearable *orders* of her *supervisor*'. The source of this issue counts "6 bound morphemes, 3 functional morphemes, and 2 lexical morphemes" for the mentioned structure and that's my problem. I can't understand how those numbers are possible!

Could you elaborate on the number and the type of morphemes (free(lexical or functional) or bound(inflectional or derivational)) used in the phrase above, PLEASE?

I really thank any help.

Comment: That depends on which language you're talking about. English has an -er/-or agentive suffix that occurs on _supervisor_, from the English verb _supervise_, but it doesn't occur in _order_, since there is no English verb *_ord_. And Latin had a prefix _super_- which doesn't occur in the English verb _supervise_ because it was already glued on in Latin and became part of the English verb and not a separate morpheme any more. Words from one language get all mixed up when they merge into another language. Morphemes are only neat in synchronic morphology problems. In real language, they're messy.

Comment: Yeah, The context phrase I've provided is in English. Thanks! @jlawler

Comment: @jlawler . And after all this; Are these statistics correct? `"There are 3 lexical morphemes: bear, order, and supervise. There are 3 functional morphemes: the, of, and her. there is a inflectional morpheme: -s. There are 3 derivational morphemes: un-, -able, and -or(-er)."` If I am correct, you are incorrect because the source of this issue counts as this: `"6 bound morphemes, 3 functional morphemes, and 2 lexical morphemes."` And that's where I'm stock. That'll be a great help, I you put light on this.
Thank you very much ,,,,

Comment: I added more explanations to the question, too...